# Folder structure when using Keras' ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras

I have a training set of images with structure like this:

```
/howler-monkey/
    1.jpg
    2.jpg
    ...jpg
/japanese-mcaque
    1.jpg
    2.jpg
    ...
```

for 10 classes.

I am trying to augment the images and save them to disk, but I would like to preserve the folder structure, so:

```
/augmented/
    /howler-monkey
        aug_1.jpg
        aug_2.jpg
    /japanese-mcaque
        aug_1.jpg
        aug_2.jpg
```

It seems when I simply run with

```
trainDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2, fill_mode='nearest')

fileIterator = trainDataGenerator.flow_from_directory('{}/training'.format(args.dataset),
    save_to_dir='{}/{}'.format(args.dataset, args.output))

i = 0
for image in fileIterator:
    if i > 10:
        break
```

It dumps augmented images in the `augmented/` folder, but it doesn't save the directory structure, making it hard to use to train.

How can I preserve the original directory structure when augmenting images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up just using `.flow()` and `pathlib` to create the directories manually:

```
trainDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2)

for path in list_images(args.dataset):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0) 

    pathlib.Path('{}/{}/{}'.format(args.dataset, args.output,
            path.split(os.path.sep)[-2])).mkdir(
        parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    print(path)
    total = 0
    for image in trainDataGenerator.flow(img, batch_size=1,
            save_to_dir='{}/{}/{}'.format(args.dataset, args.output,
            path.split(os.path.sep)[-2]), save_format='jpeg'):

            print(total)
            total += 1
            if total == 10:
                break
```

where `args.dataset` is a str which contains the training images and `args.output` is a str that contains `augmentedImages`.

Comment: Can you provide the entire code? I'm having the same problem as you